# Разворачивание CKEditor при загрузке

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Как сделать так, чтобы при загрузке ckeditor разворачивался на всю клиентскую часть браузера?

Comment: интересно - а нафига?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант такой (не пробовал)

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function () {
    var e = CKEDITOR.instances.id; // textarea id

    e.execCommand('maximize');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало. А нужно это для одного проекта при редактировании документов.